# ORMs and partial stored procedure updates

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures, orm

Imagine the following object which is mapped using an ORM :

```
public class Employee
{
    public int Id;
    public string FirstName;
    public string LastName;
}
```

If I update just the FirstName property, my ORM will usually track the property change, and generate an UPDATE statement that only updates that column, with an Id predicate.

```
UPDATE Employees SET Firstname = 'Bob' WHERE ID = 1;
```

If I now change my ORM to use a stored procedure for updates, it will send all object properties as arguments to the stored procedure.

```
EXEC sp_updateEmployee @ID = 1, @Firstname = 'Bob', @Lastname = 'Smith'
```

For larger objects, writing back all fields is likely to result in heavier UPDATES because more indexes are likely to be written to.

Is there any good pattern for managing only partial updates when your UPDATE actions are mapped to stored procedures?

Comment: What ORM are you using

Comment: At this point it's an R&D exercise. I'd like to pick one that solves this problem due to it being a VLDB. So I'm open to any ORM :-)

Answer (score 0):

This will irk new school developers, but using DataSets (untyped or not) allows this easily via a helper class)

```
public static void DynamicUpdateTable(string dbTableName, string primaryKey, DataTable table, bool deleteByFlag, params string[] ignoreColumns)
    {
        if (ignoreColumns == null)
            ignoreColumns = new string[0];

        if (table.Rows.Count == 0)
            return;

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(myConnectionString))
        using (SqlCommand da = new SqlCommand())
        {
            da.Connection = conn;
            da.Connection.Open();


            // DELETES
            string deleteSQL;

            if (deleteByFlag)
                deleteSQL = "UPDATE [" + dbTableName + "] SET Deleted = 1 WHERE [" + primaryKey + "] = @PrimaryKey";
            else
                deleteSQL = "DELETE FROM [" + dbTableName + "] WHERE [" + primaryKey + "] = @PrimaryKey";

            da.CommandText = deleteSQL;

            foreach (DataRow row in table.Select(null, null, DataViewRowState.Deleted))
            {
                da.Parameters.Clear();
                da.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PrimaryKey", row[primaryKey, DataRowVersion.Original]);
                da.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            // INSERTS  
            List<string> insertColumnNames = new List<string>();
            foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
            {
                if (!ignoreColumns.Contains(column.ColumnName) &&
                    !column.AutoIncrement &&
                     column.GetType() != typeof(byte[]))
                    insertColumnNames.Add(column.ColumnName);
            }

            string insertSQL = 
                "INSERT INTO [" + dbTableName + "] ([" + string.Join("], [", insertColumnNames.ToArray()) + "]) " + 
                "VALUES (@" + string.Join(", @", insertColumnNames.ToArray()) + ")";

            da.CommandText = insertSQL;

            foreach (DataRow row in table.Select(null, null, DataViewRowState.Added))
            {
                da.Parameters.Clear();
                foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
                {
                    if (!ignoreColumns.Contains(column.ColumnName) &&
                        // ignore auto increment primary key
                        !column.AutoIncrement &&
                        // ignore all timestamps
                        column.GetType() != typeof(byte[]))
                        da.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" + column.ColumnName, row[column]);
                }

                da.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            // DYNAMIC UPDATE         
            foreach (DataRow row in table.Select(null, null, DataViewRowState.ModifiedCurrent))
            {
                da.Parameters.Clear();

                // work out which columns have changed in the row
                List<string> changedColumns = new List<string>();
                foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
                {
                    if (!ignoreColumns.Contains(column.ColumnName) &&
                        !row[column, DataRowVersion.Original].Equals(row[column, DataRowVersion.Current]))
                    {
                        changedColumns.Add("[" + column.ColumnName + "] = @" + column.ColumnName);
                        da.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" + column.ColumnName, row[column, DataRowVersion.Current]);
                    }
                }

                // only update if there are actual changes
                if (changedColumns.Count > 0)
                {
                    string updateSQL = 
                        "UPDATE [" + dbTableName + "] SET " + string.Join(", ", changedColumns.ToArray()) +
                        " WHERE [" + primaryKey + "] = @" + primaryKey;

                    da.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" + primaryKey, row[primaryKey]);

                    da.CommandText = updateSQL;
                    da.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
        }

        table.AcceptChanges();
    }
```